# When does time pass in Norende?

Tags: bravely-default

There's a minigame where StreetPass visitors work over time to rebuild Norende. But when does time pass in Norende? Does it pass with the real-time 3DS clock, when Bravely Default is suspended, or only when playing Bravely Default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the demo (which may be different in the full game) it passes as long as the game is on, suspended or not. As long as Bravely Default is playing even if the 3ds IS CLOSED time will still pass. If Bravely Default is not playing time will not pass though.

Comment: Confirmed on the full version - time keeps on going when you leave the game running and just close the 3DS.